# JQuery dirtyForm not working on text boxes in ajaxToolkit:TabPanel

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using Asa Wilson's plugin jquery.dirtyform.js to prompt a user of unsaved changes before they nav away from a page (ASP.Net C# 3.5).

It basically loops through all controls and appends a class and handler to each input.
Controls w/i an ajaxToolkit:TabPanel are ignored, unfortunately.

I'd appreciate if anyone knows of this type of error and how to resolve it short of manually manipulating each control (as I have this logic in the master page).

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.
The content in the AJAX TabPanel wasn't rendered when the jQuery event $(document).ready() fired, thus the controls were not "watched".

I simply added an event to the rogue controls to re-fire $("form").dirty_form();

Seems to be working thus far.  I'm sure there is a more eloquent solution.